# How to inject service into listener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

My goal is to listen to the User entity via AuditTrailListener
and save the audit data into DB when insert/update/delete operations
are executed on the User. I'm able to listen and print the message after some action occures. The problem is when I want to inject instance of the AuditService into AuditTrailListener and store AuditObject data to DB. I'm getting NullPointerException. There are few options (e.g. static field) on how to resolve the problem but none of them work?

User.java

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditTrailListener.class)
public class User {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(User.class);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    
    private String userName;
}
```

AuditObject.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name="AuditObject")
public class AuditObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id=1L;  // test
    
    @Column(length=20)
    private String op="test1"; // test
}
```

AuditRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface AuditRepository extends JpaRepository<AuditObject, Long> {
    List<AuditObject> findAll();
}
```

AuditService.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor    // lombok
@Transactional
public class AuditService {
    private final AuditRepository repo;

    public Audit saveOrUpdate(Audit audit) {
        return repo.save(audit);
    }
}
```

AuditTrailListener.java

```
public class AuditTrailListener {

    static private AuditService auditService;

    @Autowired
    public void init(AuditService auditService)
    {
        AuditTrailListener.auditService = auditService;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    @PreRemove
    private void beforeAnyUpdate(User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        auditService.saveOrUpdate(new AuditObject());//java.lang.NullPointerException
    }
    
    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @PostRemove
    private void afterAnyUpdate(User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        auditService.saveOrUpdate(new AuditObject());//java.lang.NullPointerException
    }
    
    @PostLoad
    private void afterLoad(User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        auditService.saveOrUpdate(new AuditObject());//java.lang.NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to simply annotate the `AuditTrailListener` with `@Component`?

Comment: Yes, but still NullPointerException.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version do you use? This should acutally work in recent versions

Comment: Spring Boot v2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `AuditTrailListener` a Spring-managed Bean. One simple way would be by annotating it with `@Component` as follows:

```java
@Component
public class AuditTrailListener {
   (...)
}
```

Comment: With annotation @Component and without there is exactly the same problem.

Comment: In which package is `AuditTrailListener` located? Can you please add your main class `@SpringBootApplication` to your question? Thanks!